# How should I implement the three turn system in Yahtzee using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('document').ready( function() {

  function die() {
    var diceimg = ["","Die1.png", "Die2.png", "Die3.png", "Die4.png", "Die5.png", "Die6.png"]
    var selected = false;
    var firstroll = false;
    var turns = 0;
    this.value = 0;
    this.dom = null;
    this.roll = function() {
      if(!selected) { this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; }
      this.dom = $('<img class="die" src="'+diceimg[this.value]+'" height="150x" width="150px">');
      this.dom.click(function() { selected = !selected;
      });
    }
  }

  var dice = [];
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());

  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(die.firstroll === true) {
      dice[i].roll();
      $('#dice-container').append(dice[i].dom);
    }
  }

  $('#rollbutt').click(function() {
    die.firstroll = true;
    $('#dice-container').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      dice[i].roll();
      $('#dice-container').append(dice[i].dom);
    }
  });

  $('.scoreboard').click(function() {
    console.log(dice[1].value);
    console.log(dice[1].selected);
    $(this).append(dice[1].value);
  });
});
```

So I've managed to get everything working besides scoring and the 3 rolls rule and that's where I'm stuck. I tried implementing a counter called turns, and put an if testing for turns<3 in the rollbutt (rollbutton) function, but that didn't seem to work. I also tried using a while(turns<3) but that didn't work eiher. I have no idea where to place it in order to prevent further rolls after three turns, so any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: you probably need a whole different approach.  coding is 95% planning, 5% writing code when done right.  put it in a jsfiddle and ill re-write it for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

Comment: I appreciate your advice Brian, just realize that linking a beginners course on JS is slightly condescending. I'm on a short deadline (two days to be exact), so yeah I do realize things could be much clearer and efficient, but I'm doing my best with the time that I have.

Comment: Just trying to help.  Based on your code I assumed it was your first time.  Little to no indication that you have any knowledge regarding oop or even best practices. 
 Remember, negative criticism is often the most valuable.  Sooo.. your welcome?   Is someone actually paying you for this?  why would you take on a job on a short deadline when you don't even know wtf your doing.  lol  -- Anyway, since you are too busy worrying about your ego, I'll go make a fiddle and write it correctly.  Just trying to help.  If it stings, use that for motivation to impove.  No shame.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You can use a variable to hold how many times the roll button has been pressed and just increment the value.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var rolls = 0;
  $('#roll-count').html(rolls)

  function die() {
    var diceimg = ["", "Die1.png", "Die2.png", "Die3.png", "Die4.png", "Die5.png", "Die6.png"]
    var selected = false;
    var firstroll = false;
    var turns = 0;
    this.value = 0;
    this.dom = null;
    this.roll = function() {
      if (!selected) {
        this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      }
      this.dom = $(`<img class="die" src="http://www.speedymath.com/images/dice/${this.value}-border.gif" height="150px" width="150px">`);
      this.dom.click(function() {
        selected = !selected;
      });
    }
  }

  var dice = [];
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());
  dice.push(new die());

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (die.firstroll === true) {
      dice[i].roll();
      $('#dice-container').append(dice[i].dom);
    }
  }

  $('#rollbutt').click(function() {
    if (rolls === 3) return;
    rolls++
    $('#roll-count').html(rolls)
    die.firstroll = true;
    $('#dice-container').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      dice[i].roll();
      $('#dice-container').append(dice[i].dom);
    }
  });

  $('.scoreboard').click(function() {
    console.log(dice[1].value);
    console.log(dice[1].selected);
    $(this).append(dice[1].value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dice-container"></div>
<button id="rollbutt">Roll</button><span id="roll-count"></span>
<div class="scoreboard"></div>
```